# Create resizable borders for empty stage

Tags: java, css, javafx, border, stage

I have a blank `javafx.stage.Stage` with no icons *minimize*, *maximize*, and *close* `stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);`. I want to create them myself, because on the line with them will make more `Buttons`. Because I use an empty style for the `Stage`, I need to set a resizable borders for my window. There are standard ways to do this? Because to create them as a `BorderPane` and customize the dragging of the mouse is cumbersome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make resizable borders with mouse cursor position listener, it's work, I have not much time for optimized code:

```
    public class Resize {
        double eY = 0;
        double eX = 0;
        double eStrtY = 0;
        double eStrtX = 0;
        double sceneStrtY = 0;
        double sceneStrtX = 0;
        double minW = 600;
        double minH = 600;
        double w = 0;
        public Resize(Stage stage, double w) {

            Scene scene = stage.getScene();
            AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane)scene.getRoot();
    this.w = w;
    root.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
            eStrtY = e.getSceneY();
            eStrtX = e.getSceneX();
            sceneStrtY = e.getSceneY();
            sceneStrtX = e.getSceneX();
        }
    });

    root.setOnMouseMoved(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        //  double w = 8;
            double X = event.getSceneX();
            double Y = event.getSceneY();
            double sW = scene.getWidth();
            double sH = scene.getHeight();

            if(((X<w)&&(Y<w))||((X<2*w)&&(Y<w))||((Y<2*w)&&(X<w))) {
                scene.setCursor(Cursor.NW_RESIZE);
                eY = stage.getY();
                eX = stage.getX();
                root.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                        if(((eStrtX<w)&&(eStrtY<w))||((eStrtX<2*w)&&(eStrtY<w))||((eStrtY<2*w)&&(eStrtX<w))) {
                            if(stage.getHeight()+(eY-e.getScreenY())>minH) {
                                stage.setY(e.getScreenY());
                                stage.setHeight(stage.getHeight()+(eY-e.getScreenY()));
                                eY = e.getScreenY();
                            }
                            if(stage.getWidth()+(eX-e.getScreenX())>minW) {
                                stage.setX(e.getScreenX());
                                stage.setWidth(stage.getWidth()+(eX-e.getScreenX()));
                                eX = e.getScreenX();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else
                if(((X>sW-w)&&(Y<w))||((X>sW-2*w)&&(Y<w))||((X>sW-w)&&(Y<2*w))) {
                    scene.setCursor(Cursor.NE_RESIZE);
                    eY = stage.getY();
                    eX = stage.getX() + stage.getWidth();
                    root.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                        @Override
                        public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                            if(((eStrtX>sW-w)&&(eStrtY<w))||((eStrtX>sW-2*w)&&(eStrtY<w))||((eStrtX>sW-w)&&(eStrtY<2*w))) {
                                if(stage.getHeight()+(eY-e.getScreenY())>minH) {
                                    stage.setY(e.getScreenY());
                                    stage.setHeight(stage.getHeight()+(eY-e.getScreenY()));
                                    eY = e.getScreenY();
                                }
                                if(stage.getWidth()-(eX-e.getScreenX())>minW) {
                                    stage.setWidth(stage.getWidth()-(eX-e.getScreenX()));
                                    eX = e.getScreenX();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                    if(((X>sW-w)&&(Y>sH-w))||((X>sW-2*w)&&(Y>sH-w))||((X>sW-w)&&(Y>sH-2*w))) {
                        scene.setCursor(Cursor.SE_RESIZE);
                        eY = stage.getY() + stage.getHeight();
                        eX = stage.getX() + stage.getWidth();
                        root.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                            @Override
                            public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                                if(((eStrtX>sW-w)&&(eStrtY>sH-w))||((eStrtX>sW-2*w)&&(eStrtY>sH-w))||((eStrtX>sW-w)&&(eStrtY>sH-2*w))) {
                                    if(stage.getHeight()-(eY-e.getScreenY())>minH) {
                                        stage.setHeight(stage.getHeight()-(eY-e.getScreenY()));
                                        eY = e.getScreenY();
                                    }
                                    if(stage.getWidth()-(eX-e.getScreenX())>minW) {
                                        stage.setWidth(stage.getWidth()-(eX-e.getScreenX()));
                                        eX = e.getScreenX();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else
                        if(((X<w)&&(Y>sH-w))||((X<2*w)&&(Y>sH-w))||((X<w)&&(Y>sH-2*w))) {
                            scene.setCursor(Cursor.SW_RESIZE);
                            eY = stage.getY() + stage.getHeight();
                            eX = stage.getX();
                            root.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                                @Override
                                public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                                    if(((eStrtX<w)&&(eStrtY>sH-w))||((eStrtX<2*w)&&(eStrtY>sH-w))||((eStrtX<w)&&(eStrtY>sH-2*w))) {
                                        if(stage.getHeight()-(eY-e.getScreenY())>minH) {
                                            stage.setHeight(stage.getHeight()-(eY-e.getScreenY()));
                                            eY = e.getScreenY();
                                        }
                                        if(stage.getWidth()+(eX-e.getScreenX())>minW) {
                                            stage.setX(e.getScreenX());
                                            stage.setWidth(stage.getWidth()+(eX-e.getScreenX()));
                                            eX = e.getScreenX();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        else
                            if(Y<w) {
                                scene.setCursor(Cursor.V_RESIZE);
                                eY = stage.getY();
                                eX = stage.getX() + stage.getWidth();
                                root.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                                        if((eStrtY<w)&&(stage.getHeight()+(eY-e.getScreenY())>minH)) {
                                            stage.setY(e.getScreenY());
                                            stage.setHeight(stage.getHeight()+(eY-e.getScreenY()));
                                            eY = e.getScreenY();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            else
                                if(Y>sH-w) {
                                    scene.setCursor(Cursor.V_RESIZE);
                                    eY = stage.getY() + stage.getHeight();
                                    root.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                                            if((eStrtY>sH-w)&&(stage.getHeight()-(eY-e.getScreenY())>minH)) {
                                                stage.setHeight(stage.getHeight()-(eY-e.getScreenY()));
                                                eY = e.getScreenY();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                                else
                                    if(X<w) {
                                        scene.setCursor(Cursor.H_RESIZE);
                                        eX = stage.getX();
                                        root.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                                                if((eStrtX<w)&&(stage.getWidth()+(eX-e.getScreenX())>minW)) {
                                                        stage.setX(e.getScreenX());
                                                        stage.setWidth(stage.getWidth()+(eX-e.getScreenX()));
                                                        eX = e.getScreenX();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                    else
                                        if(X>sW-w) {
                                            scene.setCursor(Cursor.H_RESIZE);
                                            eX = stage.getX() + stage.getWidth();
                                            root.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                                                    if((eStrtX>sW-w)&&(stage.getWidth()-(eX-e.getScreenX())>minW)) {
                                                        stage.setWidth(stage.getWidth()-(eX-e.getScreenX()));
                                                        eX = e.getScreenX();
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            });
                                        }
                                        else
                                            if((X>w)&&(X<sW-w)&&(Y>w)&&(Y<25)) {
                                                root.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                                                        if((eStrtX>w)&&(eStrtX<sW-w-25*3)&&(eStrtY>w)&&(eStrtY<w+25)) {
                                                            stage.setX(e.getScreenX()-sceneStrtX);
                                                            stage.setY(e.getScreenY()-sceneStrtY);
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                });
                                            }
                                            else
                                                scene.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        }   
    });

    root.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
            eY = e.getScreenY();
            eX = e.getScreenX();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

*altered from a project of mine*

This is how it looks

[image]

when maximised

[image]

[package Project](https://bitbucket.org/Elltz/tutorial/downloads/ChatBubblePerfection.rar)

`Main.class`

```
public class Main extends Application {
double dragX,dragY;
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        HBox hbox = new HBox(10.0);
        hbox.setPrefHeight(70);
        hbox.setFillHeight(true);
        BackgroundFill bf = new BackgroundFill(Color.BLUEVIOLET, new CornerRadii(1), null);
        hbox.setBackground(new Background(bf));

        AnchorPane ap = new AnchorPane();

        ResponsiveButton min = new ResponsiveButton("Minimise");
        min.noDefaultFill = true;
        min.setBorder(Border.EMPTY);
        min.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.BLUEVIOLET, new CornerRadii(1), null)));
        //min.setPrefSize(32.0,32.0);
        min.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        min.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                primaryStage.setIconified(true);
            }
        });

        ResponsiveButton max = new ResponsiveButton("Maximise");
        max.setBorder(Border.EMPTY);
        max.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.BLUEVIOLET, new CornerRadii(1), null)));
        //max.setPrefSize(32.0,32.0);
        max.noDefaultFill = true;
        max.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {

                if(primaryStage.isMaximized()){
                    primaryStage.setMaximized(false);
                }else{
                    primaryStage.setMaximized(true);            
                }
            }
        });

        ResponsiveButton logout = new ResponsiveButton("Close me");
        logout.noDefaultFill = true;
        logout.setBorder(Border.EMPTY);
        logout.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.BLUEVIOLET, new CornerRadii(1), null)));
        //logout.setPrefSize(32.0,32.0);
        logout.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                primaryStage.close();
            }
        });

        Label label = new Label();
        label.setText("Custom Stage");
        label.setTextFill(Color.WHITESMOKE);
        //label.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        label.setPadding(new Insets(0.0,0.0,0.0,18.0));
        label.setFont(Font.font("Tahoma", FontWeight.BOLD, 25));
        HBox.setHgrow(label, Priority.ALWAYS);  
        hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        hbox.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                if(!primaryStage.isMaximized()){
                    dragX = primaryStage.getX() - mouseEvent.getScreenX();
                    dragY = primaryStage.getY() - mouseEvent.getScreenY();
                    hbox.setCursor(Cursor.MOVE);
                }
            }
        });
        hbox.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                if(!primaryStage.isMaximized()){
                    hbox.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
                    BackgroundFill bf = new BackgroundFill(Color.BLUEVIOLET, new CornerRadii(1), null);
                    hbox.setBackground(new Background(bf));
                }
            }
        });
        hbox.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                if(!primaryStage.isMaximized()){
                    primaryStage.setX(mouseEvent.getScreenX() + dragX);
                    primaryStage.setY(mouseEvent.getScreenY() + dragY);
                    BackgroundFill bf = new BackgroundFill(Color.BLANCHEDALMOND, new CornerRadii(1), null);
                    hbox.setBackground(new Background(bf));
                }
            }
        });
        hbox.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                if(!primaryStage.isMaximized()){
                    if (!mouseEvent.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
                        hbox.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        hbox.setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                if (!mouseEvent.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
                    hbox.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
                }
            }
        });

        HBox hbox2 = new HBox(10.0);
        HBox.setHgrow(hbox2, Priority.ALWAYS);
        hbox2.getChildren().addAll(min,max,logout);
        hbox.getChildren().addAll(label,hbox2);
        hbox2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(hbox, 0.0);AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(hbox, 5.0);AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(hbox, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(ap , 0.0);AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(ap , 40.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(ap , 5.0); AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(ap , 0.0);
        ap .setPrefSize(500, 560);

        AnchorPane main = new AnchorPane();         
        main.getChildren().addAll(hbox,ap);
        Scene sc = new Scene(main,500,500);
        sc.setRoot(main);

        Pane p = new   Pane();
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(p, 80.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(p, 60.0);
        Group root = new Group();   
        p.setPrefSize(400, 400);
        p.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.GOLD,
                null, null)));
        root.getChildren().add(p);
        ap.getChildren().add(p);
        primaryStage.setScene(sc);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Custom window");
        primaryStage.show();
        BubbledLabel bl1 = new BubbledLabel(BubbleSpec.FACE_LEFT_CENTER);
        bl1.relocate(10, 50);
        bl1.setText("I love this new Custom stage");
        bl1.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.VIOLET,
                null, null)));


        BubbledLabel bl2 = new BubbledLabel(BubbleSpec.FACE_RIGHT_CENTER);
        bl2.relocate(310, 100);
        bl2.setText("We all love it");
        bl2.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.LIGHTPINK,
                null, null)));

        BubbledLabel bl3 = new BubbledLabel(BubbleSpec.FACE_LEFT_CENTER);
        bl3.relocate(10, 150);
        bl3.setText("Nikitoslav is going love it");
        bl3.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.YELLOWGREEN,
                null, null)));


        BubbledLabel bl4 = new BubbledLabel(BubbleSpec.FACE_RIGHT_CENTER);
        bl4.relocate(165, 200);
        bl4.setText("hmmm.. you have you asked him???");
        bl4.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.GREENYELLOW,
                null, null)));

        BubbledLabel bl5 = new BubbledLabel(BubbleSpec.FACE_LEFT_CENTER);
        bl5.relocate(10, 250);
        bl5.setText("yea! yea! ");
        bl5.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.YELLOWGREEN,
                null, null)));


        BubbledLabel bl6 = new BubbledLabel(BubbleSpec.FACE_RIGHT_CENTER);
        bl6.relocate(250, 300);
        bl6.setText("Oh really!!? oh stop it!!");
        bl6.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.GREENYELLOW,
                null, null)));


        p.getChildren().addAll(bl1,bl2,bl3,bl4,bl5,bl6);

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {
     launch(args);
 }

}
```

If you just copy the codes here, change `ResponsiveButton` to Button and remove the `Anchorpane`ap` and its children, its classes are not added, but if you download the package project there is no problem.

Comment: thank you for this code. So you're suggesting for me to make borders with HBox and VBox around the scene root? Not elegant, but works, I think.

if you will allow:
close your application with System.exit(1);
because stage.close(); not close the process in MAC OS, for example

Comment: you welcome, yea, from how i see it, it will fit it better, as you can always set priority for children in the `HBox` or `VBox` and they work alright for me, also you need to nest heightproperties and widthproperties for children so as you maximise they also increase in size, starting from the stage, well i quite confused about this, because when the last Stage goes closes, the app is exited and shutdown,by means of onStop being called, so you can check if it was called actually, i do not use Mac os so i dont know but thanks for the insight also. not elegant? hmm wel pimp it :-) @Nikitoslav

Answer (score 0):

Is this link a possible solution for what you require? [How to bind stage resizing with resizing of components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10318467/how-to-bind-stage-resizing-with-resizing-of-components)

it is also possible that this link could work for you as well:

[JavaFX: autoresize stage after adding child to root parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19670357/javafx-autoresize-stage-after-adding-child-to-root-parent)

The main line of code from the second link is

```
stage.sizeToScene();
```